# how to embed mobile number with the url

Tags: objective-c

How can i embed a mobile number with the external link using objective c.
objective-c.

I  have a link from my local server. This link will give some offers according to the users mobile number. I have hard coded the link with the mobile number. Now i wanted to get the mobile number in one variable and parse this variable along with the url which is coming from my local server.

The link which i hard coded will be like 
           http://123.1.241/eService/service.asmx/offers?mobilenumber=1234456789

Instead of giving the mobile number here itself, i wanted to store this number in one variable and use that variable in the link itself.

Answer (score 1):

Depends really on the platform. On iOS for instance, you can craft a link like this:

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"tel:1234456789"]];
```

That'll prompt the user to verify that they indeed want to call that number, opting to present them with the UIAlertView the system pops up, with a "Call" and "Cancel" button.

Answer (score 0):

phone number url looks like this:  tel:1-123-456-6789